# How do I connect to rasa server(with rasa-webchat as frontend) using login data for session persistence?

Tags: chatbot, rasa

To be more detailed, I want to identify users based on their user id in the login page to load the users context from previous chats. I have seen the local and session storage options but is there a way we can embed the same based on login. Also, the bot deployed on Wordpress. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: After login you can pass the user id as custom data from the Rasa frontend to the Rasa server, does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058847/how-to-get-the-user-login-details-from-java-script-based-web-browser-in-rasa-cha/62059118#62059118?

Comment: @BeppeC I have looked into this but I wasn't sure how it worked. Does the custom user id map to a unique session id when the socket is connected? Like, if I passed the username obtained, would that mean the next time I opened the chat in a different environment, the same session id will be initialised?

Comment: Being custom data you can pass what you want: after login you have the user id (or session id) and you can pass it to the Rasa server. Next time you can get this id from a local storage (if you have stored in the storage) or obtain it again after login. You have control on the frontend of what and when you pass custom data to the Rasa backend

Comment: @BeppeC so essentially by passing custom data, I can choose which user to initiate chat with?

Comment: By that I mean use it to identify users uniquely to retrieve past conversations just like storing the session data in Rasa Webchat would do

Comment: It is a custom data so you decide what to track (could be user id or anything else), this is just a mechanism to pass custom info to the Rasa server.